# Docker for Desktop is installed but doesn't lauch

Tags: docker, windows-10, containers, hyper-v

I have installed docker for desktop on my pc but it doesn't launch at all.
What all is done: Hyper-V is installed, is running a virtual machine
                  performed the following steps:-
                  Verifying that the Virtual Machine Management service on the computer is running:

Open "Window Security"
Open "App & Browser control"
Click "Exploit protection settings" at the bottom
Switch to "Program settings" tab
Locate "C:\WINDOWS\System32\vmcompute.exe" in the list and expand it
Click "Edit"
Scroll down to "Code flow guard (CFG)" and uncheck "Override system settings"
Start vmcompute from powershell
net start vmcompute   --> "already running"

rebooted my pc twice.
tried launching the app with run as administrator option

The above didn't work.
Please tell me how to launch it!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows and you have some apps like Virtualbox or VMWare you need to uninstall them I think and I'm not sure if you need to stop virtualization.